# I keep getting com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Database 'plocal:C:\code\pos\.\database/pos' is closed

Tags: javafx, orientdb

I am building a javafx desktop Application with an orientdb local database. I keep getting 
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: 
Database 'plocal:C:\code\pos.\database/pos' is closed

if I try to access any object for the first time after I query it.
Example :

```
ODatabaseObject session = db.getSession();
    List<User> u = session.objectQuery("select from User where username = 
        :un and password = :pwd" , usernameTextfield.getText(), 
        passwordTextfield.getText());
    if( u.size() > 0 ) {
            currentUser = u.get(0) ;
            db.close();
            currentUser.getName();
    }
```

Comment: would you please add the code that opens the database.